# fadeIn div after image fade

Tags: jquery

Trying to fade in the text div on top of the images  *after* they fade?

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div id="hover"></div>
</div>

<div class="pic_info">text</div>

$('.overlay, #hover_small').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).find('#hover, .overlay_small, .pic_info').stop().animate({opacity: 0});
});

$('.overlay, #hover_small').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).find('#hover, .overlay_small, .pic_info').stop().animate({opacity: 1});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yNtm5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `animate` method includes an optional `callback` parameter that you can use after the animation is complete. ([.animate() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/))

```
$('.overlay, #hover_small').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).find('#hover, .overlay_small, .pic_info').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, function() {
        $('.pic_info').fadeIn();
    });
});

$('.overlay, #hover_small').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).find('#hover, .overlay_small, .pic_info').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, function() {
        $('.pic_info').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNtm5/6/)

Comment: Why does the text show when the page initially loads, then once you hover over then move off it fades out and then works properly after? This was the problem I was having. Do I have to hide it first? @user1506980

Comment: Yep, actually I just updated this to fix it. Initially now the text is set to `display:none` in the CSS.

Comment: Okay so now I'm having another issue when trying to pull the text up it shifts everything below it up with it. <http://jsfiddle.net/sad6J/> @user1506980

Comment: Try using `position:absolute` for the text div so you don't affect other things on the page. 
And don't forget to accept this answer if it helped you =)

Comment: So here's the site I'm working on: [trevormsmith.com](http://trevormsmith.com/). Now I'm having a problem with the hover states of the text and fades. How can I keep the image faded when rollover on text?  @user1506980

Answer (score 0):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/yNtm5/10/)**

HTML

```
  <div class="overlay">
      <div id="hover">
            <div class="pic_info"><h4><i><u>Motion</u></i></h4><h2><a href="#">'CREO' Experimental Short</a></h2></div>

      </div>
  </div>
```

```
#hover{
    background-image:url(img/creo.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:700px;
    height:300px;
    background: #000;
    display:none;
}
.overlay {
   background-image:url(img/fade/creo.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:700px;
    height:300px;
    background: red;
}
.pic_info{
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:100px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```
$('.overlay, #hover_small').hover(function() {
    $('#hover, .overlay_small').stop().fadeToggle();
});
```